Complete porting from Python to C/C++ with Cython
I'm working with a Python code (3.12) that uses Sklearn, Numpy and Panda modules.
My goal is to fully convert such Python code into C/C++ code, so avoiding the use of Python due to project requirements.
Does Cython fits my requirement? May I totally convert the Python code using Cython? I Suppose I have to convert sklearn, numpy and panda modules too.
Thanks.

I'm unsure if I correctly understand the question. Cython is for the other way, when you want to use your C or C++ code in Python. What do you mean with "porting from Python to C/C++"? If you mean, what I understand, you have to rewrite the whole code. Cython does not convert anything.

Thanks for the quick reply. My doubt was in fact  if Cython is a right tool. I would have C++ code at the end starting from Python code.

Do you want to run the C++ in a Python environment? Cython can convert Python code to C or C++ code, but it compiles it as Python modules.

No, I want to remove completely Python from my project chain.

AFAIK, there is no reliable tool to automatically port a non-trivial project. I've worked in multiple companies that paid much money for different tools and the results were so bad that we had to discard them and manually port the projects.

Cython may be branded as a sort of transpiler (but a transpiler whose main task is to generate the Python/C API overhead for you, that is to generate python modules. Which you don't want anyway). But in practice, but for some HelloWorld.py, it is more an alternative language (which is neither C, nor python) used to write ad-hoc code (not to translate existing python code, but to "transpile" code written with cython in the mind). A language whose lexicography and syntax is the one of python, but semantic and code generation is the one of C.

It may be useful, if you are a python programmer, and want to create a new python module, and don't want to code in C (either because you don't know C. Or just because you want to spare yourself the coding of Python/C API). IMHO, someone who can code C, should write their module directly in C: in the long run, they will end up doing that anyway. But people may have different opinions on that. What is more objective, is that it is not really for existing code not written with cython in the mind; and more importantly, it is just to write python modules.

No. Cython is not appropriate. It generates Python modules that use the Python C API and requires a Python interpreter to run. Even when running supposedly standalone programs it requires linking against libpython.
Additionally, sklearn, numpy and panda are a mixture of Python code and C modules that use the Python C API, so they are not something that can be compiled with Cython.
